# Replacing text in the same column

Tags: vba, excel

Can I please be assisted with coding in VBA (I haven't been able to do much). I want to replace the texts in all the cells in  column B.

When there is a specific text in a cell in column B and a specific text in a cell in column A, I want the cells in column B to be replaced to another text.
F
or example, if in a cell in column B there is either 'No' or 'Other', and in column A there is 'refused'; I want the column B's text ('No' or 'Cancel') to be replaced to 'decline'.
Would greatly appreciate help. Thanks

`Worksheets("HIA").Columns("B").Replace _
 What:="No", Replacement:="Decline", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True`

Comment: "Help" looks like "here's my code please help me fix it".  Not "here are my requirements please provide code"

Comment: @TimWilliams I have been only able to replace text in the same column. Following is the code:
Worksheets("HIA").Columns("E").Replace _
 What:="No", Replacement:="Decline", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should help:

```
Sub Example()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'change if required
    Set sht = ActiveSheet 'change as required
    
    With sht 'use with sht to save typing ActiveSheet loads of times
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row that has data
        For Row = 2 To LastRow 'loop through each row and check the values
            If (.Cells(Row, 2) = "Refused" And .Cells(Row, 1) = "No") Or (.Cells(Row, 2) = "Refused" And .Cells(Row, 1) = "Other") Then
                .Cells(Row, 1) = "Decline"
            End If
        Next Row
    End With

End Sub
```

Note the comments in the code for explanation on how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. May I please ask you to edit the code such that the columns are in reverse order. I have edited my question above accordingly.

Comment: The above answer uses the "Cells" property which refers to the cells by number rather than by name. 

The syntax is Cells([row number], [column number]). So Cells(1, 1) refers to A1 and Cells(1, 2) refers to B1 and so on. 

So when the above code says .Cells(Row, 2) = "Refused" it is looking for the word refused in the 2nd Column (B). If you want to look for refused in column A then you'd change the 2 to a 1.

I hope the above information will help you edit your code yourself. Looping through cells is a very handy skill to master!

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. Works perfect. Thanks